# How to calculate the interval betwwen 2 elements in Python

Tags: python, list

in Python, I have a list looks like following:

```
[nan, nan, 0, 0, nan, 0, 0, nan, 0, nan, 0, nan, nan, nan]
```

I would like to calculate the interval between 0s, or I would like to turn it into following:

```
[nan, nan, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, nan, nan, nan]
```

The average interval is 1.
Is there any proper way to perform this?

Comment: You say you want to count the interval; what happens if you had `[nan, 0, nan, nan, 0]`? Should that be `2` instead of `1`?

Comment: Are you using numpy? What is `nan`?

Comment: @Alex almost certainly numpy.

Comment: @roganjosh would have assumed but OP has the `list` tag

Comment: _"I would like to calculate the interval between 0, or **...**"_ ??? Between 0 and _what_???

Comment: @roganjosh it should be 2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: @Alex Yep, numpy.nan

Comment: @AGNGazer Between two 0s

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick script I hope does what you are asking for.

```
nan = "nan"
list = [nan, nan, 0, 0, nan, 0, 0, nan, 0, nan, 0, nan, nan, nan]
occurances = list.count(0)
counter = 0
after1 = False
newlist = []
for I in list:
    if I == 0:
        counter += 1

        after1 = True
    elif after1 == True and counter < occurances:
        I = 1
    else:
        after1 = False
    newlist.append(I)
print(newlist)
```

It returns:

```
['nan', 'nan', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']
```